# Can i go logout page on inactivity

Tags: spring-security, session-timeout

Please suggest me solution to go logout page on inactivity just like bank pages will do.
After session timeout, app has to display login page to login to the application. I am using Spring acegi security. Your help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is indescribably annoying.

Comment: I have the requirement to go login page on inactivity. This we will normally observe in Bank application. If we loged in our bank accound, after inactivity it automatically redirect to login page. I am not understnding how to do this? Thats why i am asking suggetions.

Comment: I have answered for same question on following link. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371498/can-i-go-logout-page-on-inactivity/18916972#18916972>

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is, you could place a javascript (or [Meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh)) in your web page, which makes a request to the server *after the timeout period*.  This will automagically redirect to the login page.

Comment: Thank you. How can we detect this session timeout in Java script

Comment: Session timeout is configured in your app server.  Use the value.

Answer (score 1):

you have to just put this in your jsp page "head" tag

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="${pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval};url=login">
```

In above url you have to set your login controller path. 
After session expired your page will be redirected to the url specified by you.