# grails 3.0.7 logout view

Tags: session, grails

I have a Grails 3.0.7 web application that does not have a login page, but needs to keep track of timeouts (i.e. when user does not do anything for say 10 mins). I have a HttpSessionListener implementation by which i can trap sessionCreated and sessionDestroyed events. On a sessionDestroyed event, i would like to show a decent timeout page.

I am wired in the HTTPSessionListener implementation via resources.groovy like so :-
    import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletListenerRegistrationBean
    import com.sample.MySessionController

```
beans = {     
mySessionListener(ServletListenerRegistrationBean) 
{
    listener = bean(MYSessionController)
}
}
```

and in my Session Listener implementation i have the following

```
class MySessionController 
implements HttpSessionListener, Events
{
void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event)
{
println ("Session Created with id :- " + session.id)
}
void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event)
{
println ("Session Destroyed with id :- " + session.id)
}
def cleanUpSession()
{
    println "Your session has timed out and has been cleaned..."
    render "Your session has timed out and has been cleaned..."
}
}
```

Question is :- how do i redirect to a view in the sessionDestroyed event?

Answer (score 0):

As this is a parallel event, You can't. 
After timeout I'd create a session variable (i.e. `session.timeout = true`)
that is being checked using JS, sending requests to controller and asking if user is still "active" - `if session.timeout!=true`. 
And when session is created, you reset the `session.timeout` variable to `null` or false. 
And back to .gsp - if Ajax request returns negative response, You just redirect to wanted page (or do whatever).

Comment: Ok - but how do sites like bankofamerica do it? The banking sites auto redirect you to a timeout page after a few minutes of inactivity.

Comment: maybe this can help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371498/can-i-go-logout-page-on-inactivity. meta refresh is the way to go!